# Handle IOS app open from tapping on Now Playing

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using SwiftAudio to play audio, I want to detect when audio playing in background mode and app become active from tapping on Now Playing.

```
NotificationCenter
 .default
 .addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive),
                               name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
                               object: nil)

@objc func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
   print("applicationDidBecomeActive")
}
```

right now I'm trying this way but it trigger applicationDidBecomeActive even when user open app from icon.

If there any other ways to know when user tapping on Now Playing, please let me know.
I'm very new to IOS development and Swift

Edit: I guess I can detect how app is entered foreground from NowPlaying by passing the expected objectsender to addObserver instead of passing nil object. I tried many times but still don't know what sender object it it.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific notification for the app being launched through `Now Playing.` You can mostly detect your app entering the foreground again, you already showed one technique and if you use scene delegate `sceneWillEnterForeground` will also notify you when your app is in the foreground.

Comment: @ShawnFrank sadly because I want to know how the app is entered foreground again, either from tapping on icon or Now Playing or notification. it's quite suprising if there is no way to know that

Comment: Have you seen any app that somehow responds to this? I checked Spotify and Youtube Music, both just open the app without navigating anywhere or any other UI change.

Comment: @PylypDukhov actually I only saw this action on Android before, it's my bad that I didn't check other IOS apps. I spent past few days to work on this, perhaps it's impossible on IOS

Comment: Yeah, I've used swizzling and some other methods to check all notification sent(including private API) in the app and all the methods called on `AppDelegate`(including privates too), it doesn't seems to be any specific action called in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpnowplayinginfocenter)

When your app is active again, you can check the `nowPlayingInfo` and `playbackState` to customise what you actually want to do in your app.

What is the difference between launching from Notification or Now Playing in your case? Maybe clarifying this a bit more will allow us to craft a better solution to your problem.

Comment: nowPlayingInfo and playbackState don't help in this case